# Reasons not to recall after slaying Baron without the enemy team around

Tags: league-of-legends

Why would you not recall after a baron if dragon is not up the enemy team is not around and losing towers is out of the question? Recalling gives you better items, health and thus more team fight potential.

Comment: Stick with the team. If more people needs to recall, everyone should. If you're the only one, having the buff to push as a team and force a teamfight will be better.

Answer (score 15):

Why would you? Perhaps there are waves to clear, minion camps to farm, etc.

There are always things to do on the map. Yes a lot of the time it makes sense to recall, but just as often there is something you can take. Frequently I kill baron then find myself 100 gold short on an item so go clear a jungle camp or similar before recalling.

Just having taken one objective does not by itself mean "recall now", it just adds more gold into the picture that may mean it is time to recall.

**Being good at LoL is a lot about tactical flexibility, there is no solid rule to say you should always do X when Y.**

Comment: `Being good at LoL is a lot about tactical flexibility, there is no solid rule to say you should always do X when Y.` highlight that one please!

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Done

Answer (score 1):

3 reasons:

- Defend another objective
- Push a lane
- Clear pushing minion waves

All of these are situational and a lot of the time it is better to avoid fighting the enemy 5v5 after killing the baron as you will probably have been weakened and need to heal.

Everything is situational though.

Comment: Not only are you weakened, but you normally have abilities on cooldown,  have lost some vision and had lanes shoved towards you

Answer (score 0):

I often find that the enemy team, in soloQ, will have some players that are aware of the possibility that we are doing baron and others just disregarding that. Hence, one or two players will come to check while others are farming lanes. Makes for easy kills if you stick around after you've taken the baron and opens up other objectives (towers) once the enemy team is one or two members short.